# Adding percentage labels within-groups for pre-post cagetorical data ggplot barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am new to R and  am having some trouble adding percentage labels to a pre-post bar chart. The data are similar to this:

```
pre<-c("yes", "no", "no", "maybe", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes")
post<-c("no", "no", "maybe", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "maybe")
dat<-as.data.frame(cbind(pre,post)
```

With a ton of help from this site, I have figured out how to create the bar chart I would like using the following code:

```
dat %>%
  gather(key,value) %>%
  mutate(value_ordered=factor(value, levels=c("no", "maybe","yes"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=value_ordered,fill=key)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=(..count../sum(..count..))), position = "dodge") +
  scale_y_continuous(label=percent) +
  xlab("Pre/post") + ylab("") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1), legend.title=element_blank())
```

which produces this plot:
[pre/post plot][1]
apologies, I am new to the site and it won't let me post an image yet.

What I am hoping to do is add within-group percentage text above each bar for comparison, so all of the "pre" bars add up to 100% and all of the "post" bars add up to 100%, but most of what I'm finding provides percentage text above each bar for the entire data set, not within each group. I hope this makes sense. Thanks for any insight or assistance.

Comment: you can upload image by following the instructions given in the link: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344851/how-do-you-add-a-screenshot-image-to-your-stack-overflow-post

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to create a column outside of `ggplot` that will provide the cumulative sum of each variable. So, in addition to the `value_ordered` column you create, you can add new columns for the count and the cumulative count like this:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

d <- dat %>% pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "Names", values_to = "Values") %>%
  mutate(value_ordered=factor(Values, levels=c("no", "maybe","yes")))%>%
  group_by(Names, value_ordered) %>% summarise(Count = n()) %>%
  mutate(Percent = Count / sum(Count)*100)  

# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   Names [2]
  Names value_ordered Count Percent
  <chr> <fct>         <int>   <dbl>
1 post  no                6      60
2 post  maybe             2      20
3 post  yes               2      20
4 pre   no                3      30
5 pre   maybe             1      10
6 pre   yes               6      60
```

Now, you can use this column `CumPer` as a label for each bars of your histogram in the following code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(d, aes( x= value_ordered, y = Percent/100, fill = Names, label = paste(Percent,"%")))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge())+
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(.9), vjust = -0.5)+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) + 
  xlab("Pre/post") + ylab("") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1), legend.title=element_blank())
```

[image]
Does it look what you are expecting ?

Comment: I think you want `label = paste(Percent, '%')` (not `CumPer`)

Comment: I think the OP wants labels "add up to 100" per group, so that's why I proposed a cumulative sum of percentage. But maybe I misunderstood the expected output.

Comment: Thank you for your response! This is close- the percentage text is what I am looking for visually, but the actual numbers don't add up- the "pre" adds up to 170%. I am looking to show the difference in percentage of "no", "yes" and "maybe" responses in pre vs post data that correspond to the bars. For example, the "post, maybe" response text would be 20%, not 80%.

Comment: Yes! Using label=paste(percent,'%') worked. Thank you all so much!

Comment: Apologies, one other question. I just tried this on my dataset, and it works well except it gives the percentage labels in about 15 significant digits. Is there a way to limit the digits to 4?

Comment: I have edited my answer accordingly to your comments. Sorry for the mis-understanding. Regarding the number of significant digits, you can try to do `label = paste(round(Percent,4),"%")`. Let me know if it is working.